# MySQL UNION tables GROUP by column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `searches` and `recommended_searches`.  Both have two columns `id` and `keyword`

searches table

```
id | keyword 
1  | one 
2  | two 
3  | one 
4  | one 
5  | two
6  | one
```

recommended_searches table

```
id | key 
1  | two 
2  | two 
3  | one 
4  | two 
5  | two
6  | one
```

I use this query to return count of each keyword in searches table

```
SELECT keyword, count(*) as cnt FROM searches GROUP BY keyword ORDER by cnt DESC
```

and this query for recommended

```
SELECT keyword, count(*) as cnt FROM recommended_searches GROUP BY keyword ORDER by cnt DESC
```

I want to GROUP by key on these two tables but have `cnt` for search table and `recommended_cnt` for recommended_search.  This is so i can ORDER BY based on table type e.g. sort by recommended searches.

```
SELECT keyword, count(*) as cnt FROM searches
UNION ALL
SELECT keyword, count(*) as recommended_cnt FROM recommended_searches
GROUP BY keyword ORDER by recommended_cnt DESC
```

How do i return both `cnt` and `recommended_cnt`?  I tried above and not working.

i want a result like

```
Array(
[keyword] => one
[cnt] => 4
[recommended_cnt] => 2
);

Array(
[keyword] => two
[cnt] => 2
[recommended_cnt] => 4
);
```

Comment: Side note: key is a MySQL keyword you can better change the column name

Comment: Different alias names for the same column within a UNION ALL will not work..If you want to a able to sort on table you need to add a column position for example 1 for the first select and 2 for the second select.

Answer (score 2):

Put the counts in different columns in the two subqueries.

```
SELECT `key`, MAX(cnt) AS cnt, MAX(recommended_cnt) AS recommended_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT `keyword` AS `key`, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 0 AS recommended_cnt
    FROM searches
    GROUP BY `key`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `key`, 0 AS cnt, COUNT(*) AS recommended_cnt
    FROM recommended_searches
    GROUP BY `key`
) AS x
GROUP BY `key`
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb538/2)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a UNION, you want a JOIN between them.

```
SELECT a.keyword, a.cnt AS cnt, b.cnt AS cnt_recommended
FROM
  (SELECT keyword, count(*) as cnt FROM searches GROUP BY keyword ORDER by cnt DESC) as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT keyword, count(*) as cnt FROM recommended_searches GROUP BY keyword ORDER by cnt DESC) as b
  ON a.keyword = b.keyword
GROUP BY a.keyword
ORDER BY ...
```

This will join the two queries and give the counts separately for them. Depending on your requirements the join type may be different.